# I need to make this page full width, but I can't figure out the CSS to change

Tags: css

Firstly, the site is behind a membership, so I can't direct you to it, but I can explain in detail.

The wordpress site in question has a page that displays a timeline which is loaded from external javascript.

When I use Chrome console to inspect the code, I find that the CSS that controls the result I want is found in `<div class="site-inner">` and the change comes when I alter the `width`.  Here is the CSS that's found for `site-inner`:

```
.site-inner {
    clear: both;
    margin: 200px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

If I uncheck `width: 960px;` I get the result I'm looking for, however, if I make that change in the theme's *custom CSS* editing area, it affects the entire site (all pages and posts), and not just that page.

I *do* have the option to define a custom class for the `body` or `content` *on that page* when editing in Wordpress, but I can't figure out why when I create that custom class, then define the CSS for that class in the custom CSS for the theme, that the change doesn't occur for that page.

If, for example, I defined `timeline` in the body field for the post as the custom CSS class, then add to the theme's CSS:

```
.timeline {
    width: unset;
}
```

-or-

```
.site-inner .timeline {
    width: unset;
}
```

Nothing happens.  I don't really know what I'm doing, so I'm just poking holes until something works.  What I do know is that the only way I've been able to model the change is by altering what's found in `.site-inner` above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the problem, but your classes are the wrong way round in your second example, it should be:

```
.timeline .site-inner {
    width: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I figured it out, although I don't know if it's exactly what's needed.

I added both a custom body and custom content class to that post only.  One I called `.content-timeline` and the other `.body-timeline` accordingly.  After reloading the page, I confirmed that `.body-timeline` was now found in the `<body>` tag of the HTML.

Then, I started tinkering with the CSS in console and I came up with...

```
body.body-timeline .site-inner {
    width: unset;
}
```

...which seems to work.

### Yay me?